# Who Instantiated My Factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that's being instantiated 3 times and I've read some good posts on the possible causes.

When debugging the app in a browser, if you break on the factory, is there a way to tell what controller has caused the factory to be instantiated?

`Update:`

Here's a fragment from the factory. I'm setting a breakpoint where the `settings` variable is set and it is called 3 times when the app is started or the page is loaded.

```
angular.module('ts')
  .factory('usergridFactory', function ($cookieStore, $location, $q) {
     var localFunctions = {
        createSettings: function (settingsObj) {
          ...
         },
     }
    ...
    var settings = localFunctions.getSettings();
    return localFunctions;
  });
```

Comment: I'd debug from each controller. Just throw a debugger in each one and see which one throws the console error

Comment: A factory function (which creates a service) is not instantiated by controllers - it is instantiated by Angular between the "config" and the "run" phases...  So, at the very least, your description of the issue is confusing... show some code, then we could help

Comment: Also provide how you deduced it is being instantiated 3 times

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I've updated the question above.